# How Do I get the DataBase Data using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Here's my code:

```
import model.Usuario;

import org.hibernate.Session;  
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;  
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;  
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;  
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;  

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HibernateMain {  

 public static void main(String[] args) {  

  Configuration configuration=new Configuration();  
  configuration.configure();  
  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
ServiceRegistry sr= new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();  
  SessionFactory sf=configuration.buildSessionFactory(sr);  

  Usuario user1=new Usuario();  
  user1.setNombreUsuario("nombreUsuario");
  user1.setClaveUsuario("claveUsuario");
  user1.setId(5);
  user1.setLoginUsuario("loginUsuario");
  user1.setTipoUsuario("A");
  user1.setEstadoUsuario("A");
  Session ss=sf.openSession();  
  ss.beginTransaction();  
 //saving objects to session  

  ss.getTransaction().commit();  
  ss.close();  

 }  

}
```

I want to verify if user1 is in my DB, how do I do it?
I've already made the hibernate.cfg.xml, and the class Usuario is an entity of one of my tables in my DB(I'm using Postgres and Eclipse IDE btw)

Thanks

Comment: In another transaction you can call session.get(Class clazz, Serializable id) method which would return null if the entity is not in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many was to retrieve data from database, its all depends upon the situation we need to use

- If you want to retrieve the data's alone from the datatabase you can simply use
  get(), load() method which retrieve the data from database and store it in the pojo classes , so whenever you need you can use it.

  `Eg.`

  `Parent parent = (Parent)session.load(Parent.class, serializableId);\\serializableId    will the reference key`

  **[More..](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/different-between-session-get-and-session-load/)**
- If you want to retriev the data based on some defined conditions you can use `HQL` query based retrieval concept

  `Eg.`

  `Query query = session.createQuery("from Parent as a where a.fName='Raj'");`

  [**More..**](http://www.javatpoint.com/questionanswer.jsp?thread=3548)
- If you want to retrieve a data from data , that continos based on dynamic means you can go ahead with `HibernateCriteria`

  `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);`
  **[More..](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-Example.html)**

**See also..**

- **[Precedure to retrieve data from database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FV1yv7fvDQ)**